# Composite of two filtered SVG files

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to implement a visual 'diff' strategy for printed circuit boards. The intent is to highlight 'new' additions in blue and old parts of the design (removed) in red. I have two b&w svg files each of which represent a particular revision of a single layer of the board. These are generated programatically. They look something like this [png image of example svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8TEY.png)- I cannot upload an .svg directly but there are a couple of examples here;

[3c9fec_F_Cu.svg](https://pastebin.com/NDaAxrMz)

[75d8f4_F_Cu.svg](https://pastebin.com/b1LTDFuZ)

I have applied two separate feColorMatrix filters, one filter to version 1 & the other version 2  and have then placed both filtered images, positioned absolutely so they overlay each other, within a single `<div>`.

This works in Chrome but fails in other browsers (have tried both Safari and Firefox).

[Result in Chrome (desired):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBQlw.png)

I have attempted to apply the feColorMatrix filter directly and merge the result files but that does not work at all in any browser.

My current successful code (for Chrome):

```css
.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<svg width="1123px" height="794px" viewBox="50 0 600 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                    <filter id="f1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <feColorMatrix result="original" id="c1" type="matrix" values="1   0   0   0   0
                                                    0   1   0   1   0
                                                    0   0   1   1   0
                                                    0   0   0   1  0 " />
                    </filter>
                    <filter id="f2" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <feColorMatrix result="original" id="c2" type="matrix" values="1   0   0   1   0
                                            0   1   0   0   0
                                            0   0   1   0   0
                                            0   0   0   .5   0" />
                    </filter>

                </defs>
            <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" filter="url(#f1)" xlink:href="../../75d8f4/ThermocoupleLogger-F_Cu.svg" style="position:absolute;" />    
            <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" filter="url(#f2)" xlink:href="../../3c9fec/ThermocoupleLogger-F_Cu.svg" style="position:absolute;" />
            </svg>
    </div>
```

My alternative attempt with a feMerge:

```html
<div class="gallery">
<svg width="1123px" height="794px" viewBox="50 0 600 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                    <filter id="f1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <feColorMatrix xlink:href="../../75d8f4/ThermocoupleLogger-F_Cu.svg" result="one" type="matrix" 
                                    values="1   0   0   0   0
                                            0   1   0   1   0
                                            0   0   1   1   0
                                            0   0   0   1  0 " />
                    </filter>

                    <filter id="f2" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <feColorMatrix xlink:href="../../3c9fec/ThermocoupleLogger-F_Cu.svg" result="two" type="matrix"
                                    values="1   0   0   1   0
                                            0   1   0   0   0
                                            0   0   1   0   0
                                            0   0   0   .5   0" />
                    </filter>

                    <filter id="composite">
                        <feMerge>
                        <feMergeNode in="one"/>
                        <feMergeNode in="two"/>
                        </feMerge>
                    </filter>

                </defs>

<g filter="url(#composite)"></g>

</svg>
</div>
```

I would value any advice that would allow me to achieve this with some degree of cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version is mostly right - but add a height attribute directly to your image tag - SVG is fussy about dimensions & Chrome often accepts things it shouldn't. img and image tags are different elements, so that height:auto isn't applying to your image tags. Also - there is a limited number of CSS styles that apply to SVG sub-elements - when in doubt stick to SVG attributes. And remove the `position: absolute` - positioning in SVG is absolute by default.

The second version won't work for numerous reasons. feColorMatrix doesn't take an xlink:href as an input - you have to import an external file into a filter using feImage first and add a `result` attribute to it. You can then reference the result in the `in`attribute of your feColorMatrix. Filters can only reference a `result` within the same filter - so referencing `one` and `two` from the `id=composite` filter won't work. Lastly, filtering an empty `g` tag won't work - it doesn't have any dimensions so the filter area is zero. So ... use this tweaked version of your first try.

```css
.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<svg width="1123px" height="794px" viewBox="50 0 600 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                    <filter id="f1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <feColorMatrix result="original" id="c1" type="matrix" values="1   0   0   0   0
                                                    0   1   0   1   0
                                                    0   0   1   1   0
                                                    0   0   0   1  0 " />
                    </filter>
                    <filter id="f2" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <feColorMatrix result="original" id="c2" type="matrix" values="1   0   0   1   0
                                            0   1   0   0   0
                                            0   0   1   0   0
                                            0   0   0   .5   0" />
                    </filter>

                </defs>
            <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" filter="url(#f1)" xlink:href="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/beacon.svg"  />    
            <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" filter="url(#f2)" xlink:href="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/adobe.svg"  />
            </svg>
    </div>
```

You can also do a more elegant version by using feComposite's xor operator. Mouse over to see the effect.

```css
svg :hover {
  filter: url(#diff);
}
```

```html
<svg width="1600px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 1600 800">
<defs>
  <filter id="diff" x="20%" y="0%" width="80%" height="100%" >
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 1 0" result="blue-original"/>
    <feImage x="-100" y="0" width="800" height="600" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32648/SVG-Test%201.svg">
    </feImage>
       <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 1 0"/> 
    <feComposite operator="xor" in="blue-original"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>



<image  xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32648/SVG-test2.svg" x="-100" y="0" width="800" height="600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
  
  <image  xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32648/SVG-Test%201.svg" x="500" y="0" width="800" height="600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you - that is very helpful advice and your solution works on Safari and Firefox correctly. The second version was one of several variants that I had tried without success - I can now see where I was going wrong. Now I need to work out how to autoscale it.

Comment: Ah got it, the problem for the second snippets' feImage positioning in FF is caused by `preserveAspectRatio`, not sure who's right here, but FF needs it to be set everywhere or nowhere, while Chrome doesn't like [when it's set on feImage](https://jsfiddle.net/zukq621L/), so the best might be to keep it mid meet everywhere: https://jsfiddle.net/m5rcwkob/